# How to take different approaches based on whether Javascript is enabled or not?

Tags: javascript, html, json, hyperlink

We're using JSON in some parts of our **PHP** project. The edit part has been programmed by JSON, so the href part contains something like below:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="button">Edit</a>
```

We want to check that if Javascript is disabled then change the URL as follow, because the above link would not work if JS is disabled:

```
<a href="./edit.php?id=12&text=some_text_here" id="button">Edit</a>
```

We tried `<noscript>`, but we gain no success. how to do something like above, we're stuck here.
I appreciate in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<a href="./edit.php?id=12&text=some_text_here" id="button">Edit</a>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  // ...or however you assign a click handler to the element
  document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
    // Do Javascript stuff here
    return false;
  };
</script>
```

If you return `false` from your click handler, the Javascript-enabled browser will not navigate to the link's location. When Javascript is disabled the link will be followed as normal.

Comment: You hit the nail in the head.

Answer (score 8):

Default to your non-Javascript state, then use Javascript to cancel the following of the link.  Users without Javascript will then follow the link, and those that have it enabled will not.

Comment: Wow! I didn't think about it that way. tnx.

Comment: That's the only way to do it. The `href` attribute should never contain `javascript:void();` or a blank hash (e.g. `href="#"`). That's bad practice.

Comment: The main reason is that a purpose of a link is to point at another page. So imagine someone middle-clicks on that link to open it in a new tab, or right-clicks to open in in a new window - it won't work. For accessibility reasons, you need to make sure that the link will take you to somewhere sensible. If you really don't want your link to take you anywhere, you can create a "fake" link by having an element with `cursor: pointer` in it's css (so you get the pointer cursos when you mouse over the element).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can build your page normally using the php link `href="./edit.php?id=12&text=some_text_here"` and when your document is loaded execute a javascript function that will replace the `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag with `javascript:void(0);`

Example of the function with jquery:

```
$('a.button').attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
```

If the user doesn't have Javascript then the `href` attribute won't be updated.

Comment: They'll want to be doing something with the user action, so rather than overwriting the "href" attribute, it makes more sense to just attach a "click" listener, and return false.

Comment: actually it should be a#button not a.button, but thanks anyway. +1

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use what is know as ["progressive enhancement"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement). This basically means, you write your HTML as if JavaScript is not enabled, then use JavaScript to enhance the features.

This is usually achieved by attaching events, modifying the DOM etc. within a function that is called on page load.